# Как получить содержимое элемента определённого блока?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Есть несколько блоков у которых есть свой заголовок и кнопка. Нужна помощь со скриптом, который бы при нажатии на эту кнопку брал заголовок блока, в котором была нажата эта кнопка. В JS особо не силён.

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block block1">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <button>Push</button>
</div>
<div class="block block2">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <button>Push</button>
</div>
<div class="block block3">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <button>Push</button>
</div>
<div class="block block4">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <button>Push</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Без использования стрелочных функций (для новичков):**

> Также стоит обратить внимание на то, что `IE10` не поддерживает функции `forEach` и `addEventListener`. Поэтому моё решение без их использования. В IE можно использовать `attachEvent` вместо `addEventListener`.

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
for(var but in buttons)
{
 buttons[but].onclick = function(event)
 {
  var parentNode = event.target.parentNode; //div class="block"
  console.log(parentNode.querySelector('h1').innerHTML);
 };
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block block1">
  <h1>Title №1</h1>
  <button>Push</button>
</div>
<div class="block block1">
  <h1>Title №2</h1>
  <button>Push</button>
</div>
<div class="block block1">
  <h1>Title №3</h1>
  <button>Push</button>
</div>
<div class="block block1">
  <h1>Title №4</h1>
  <button>Push</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button')
  .forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', ev => {
    ev.target.parentNode.querySelector('h1').textContent += '.';
  }))
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block block1">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <button>Push</button>
</div>
<div class="block block1">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <button>Push</button>
</div>
<div class="block block1">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <button>Push</button>
</div>
<div class="block block1">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <button>Push</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
[...document.getElementsByClassName('block')].forEach(block => 
  block.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].onclick = e => 
    console.log(block.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].innerHTML)
);
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block block1">
  <h1>Title 1</h1>
  <button>Push</button>
</div>
<div class="block block1">
  <h1>Title 2</h1>
  <button>Push</button>
</div>
<div class="block block1">
  <h1>Title 3</h1>
  <button>Push</button>
</div>
<div class="block block1">
  <h1>Title 4</h1>
  <button>Push</button>
</div>
```